# How do I execute a method after a successful async action in React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to execute some code after a successful async action using React Saga. Ideally I would return a Promise to achieve that, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I also tried to use the componentDidUpdate method but it's not executed after the action. How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add your code example/snippet. So that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a call back function when you are calling the action. And after the successful completion of the async operation you can execute the callback function inside the saga.